# Chai-HTTP: Test Promise without trying expect() inside then() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, promise, chai-http

Suppose there are two js files called main.js and test.js. main.js is the code that I intend to test it by Mocha and Chai. For that, I created test.js that includes `expect()` function. `expect()` is a Chai method and takes assessment the result we expect (Is the main function for testing code).

In main.js, There is a request method that I need to test it. The request method is a Promise and is a thenable function. As I read [Chai doc](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/), I should try `expect()` inside the callback of `.then()`, just like this:

```
chai.request(app)
  .put('/user/me')
  .send({ password: '123', confirmPassword: '123' })
  .then(function (res) {
     expect(res).to.have.status(200);
  })
```

Hence, I should merge main.js to test.js. So, because of any modify on main.js, I must duplicate that change on test.js too. While, I need to include entire of main.js by `require()` in test.js and test it there. So my question is:

How can I test a request method by `expect()` in such a way that the request method remains in main.js and `expect()` remains in the test.js, there is no need to try request method in the test.js (Like `chai.request(app)`) and there is no need to try `expect()` inside of the `then()` callback (Like the mentioned code)?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's unclear. How about `async/await`?

Comment: @LinDu I modified and clarified question.

Comment: See this post for how you could use the Chai-HTTP for testing your web APIs: [Post request via Chai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697763/post-request-via-chai) and [How can I return the response from my api when testing with chai-http and Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65598586/how-can-i-return-the-response-from-my-api-when-testing-with-chai-http-and-jest).

Comment: @prasad_ The first link talks about sending request by chai. The second doesn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway.